# Need to write LDAP expression

Tags: ldap, ldap-query

Hi I have an issue in which a particular user always gets locked because of ldap lookup failure. We would this account shold never get locked irrespective of failure login attempts. Currently, we have mapping as below for password:
`expr:user=(user)?(user):user`

Now, we want a particular user (like testuser@mydomain.com) to consider some hardcoded password. i.e.
If user is testuser@mydomain.com, then it should always take the password from the mapping section otherwise..it should work as earlier.   Can someone suggest the mapping/expression to achieve this?

Comment: Which Ldap server vendor?  What application?

Comment: @jwilleke Hello ..it is MS Active dir and the application is Java application deployed on Jboss